# NetworkX add_nodes_from doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, networkx

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> g = nx.Graph()
>>> g.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], carved=False)
>>> g[1]
{}
>>> nx.get_node_attributes(g, "carved")
{1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False, 5: False}
>>>
```

Shouldn't I be getting the "carved" attribute when I type 'g[1]'?
The following works:

```
>>> g[1]
{}
>>> g[1]["carved"] = True
>>> g[1]
{'carved': True}
>>>
```

What am I missing here, why isn't the "carve" attribute being applied as in the second example? I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows. I updated my install of networkx, thinking maybe I had an older version?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you intended to use `g.node[1]` instead of `g[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

TL/DR: use `g.node[u]` to get attributes of the node `u`.  `g[u]` is something else altogether.

---

The underlying data structure is that `g` is basically a dictionary.  The nodes are keys of `g`, and if, say, `1` is a key of `g`, then `g[1]` is a dictionary whose keys are the neighbors of the node `1`.

So after placing the nodes into `g`, you haven't put in any edges.  The fact that `g[1]` is empty reflects the fact that `1` has no neighbors.  Once you go and directly edit the underlying data structure by setting `g[1]["carved"] = True`, you'll find that now `g.neighbors(1)` is `['carved']`, and that `g` now has an edge between `1` and `'carved'` and that edge has attribute `True` (from `g.edge[1]['carved']`.  But because you directly edited the data structure, `g.nodes()` is not aware that `'carved'` has been created as a node.  This is clearly not what you want.

Instead, use `g.node[u]` to get the attributes of node `u` and `g.edge[u][v]` to get any attribute of an edge from `u` to `v`.